# Electrical circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

What exactly is a pair of terminals in definition of a port in an electrical circuit below this image? I can't imagine it

[image]

[image]

Comment: you see one every day ... look at a power outlet on a wall ... then look at the end of a power cord on your computer, or your toaster, that's another ... headphone jack is another ... headphone plug is another

Comment: yes. But I am stuck for the definition of terminal and when I pair two serial terminals I get a pair of terminals

Comment: what do you mean by `serial terminal`?

Comment: It makes a terminal the same mean as of pair of terminals. This is my thinking

Comment: You're still at a very basic level here.  You're assuming this "terminal" is something tangible.   There is no "terminal" in a physical sense.  The word here is being used as meaning "this is where something is connected to the circuit".   What that "something" is doesn't matter at all.

Comment: Oh, thanks so much.

Comment: "Terminal" literally means "end." You find a railroad terminal at the end of the line, a terminal illness ends your life, etc. In electronics, a physical _terminal_ is something you attach to the end of a wire. But, there's also another meaning, because what use is a wire that goes nowhere? In electronics, terminals are _connection points._

Answer (score 6):

Your coursework is setting up some abstract definitions for the things which follow.  Concretely, in your example:

- A **circuit** is a red box
- A **terminal** is a black line entering a red box
- A **port** is a pair (ie, 2) black lines entering a red box (through which a current might flow)

Comment: Also, the current entering one terminal of a port will equal the current, leaving the other terminal of that same port.

Comment: @relayman357 ... I expect that is on one of the very next slides. :-)